# How to add a php mail() link to the body of an automated 'subscription expired' email?

Tags: php

I need to add a link into the body of the email message which is sent when the user's subscription is finished. This link should then send an email to an address which states that 'users name' wants to renew their subscription. So i need to do a php mail() inside of a php mail(), if you understand me! Also, after they click the link, they should get a thankyou message. The php code for the current 'sendExpiryEmail' function is below. Hope you can help! Thanks.

public function sendExpiryEmail($emails){

```
    foreach($emails as $email){

        $name = $email['name'];

        $emailaddress = $email['email'];

        $expirydate = date('jS F Y',strtotime($email['datetime_expire']));



        $subject = "AZ China Report expiry reminder";



        $body = '<p><img src="http://az-china.com/images/azchina_logo_email.jpg"></p>

                <p>Dear '.$name.',<br /><br />

                We hope you have been enjoying your subscription to the Black China Report.<br /><br />

                We aim to meet the needs of our readers, by de-mystifying the China market, and by providing accurate, current and pertinent facts and analysis.<br />

                We have some exciting new initiatives planned in the coming months.<br /><br />

                Your Black China Report subscription will expire on '.$expirydate.'.<br /><br />

                <strong>Renewing your subscription is easy.</strong><br /><br />

                Simply click here (link to mail()) and we will send you an order form and details on how to pay.<br /><br />

                If we can be any further assistance, please do not hesitate to contact us! <br /><br />

                Yours sincerely, <br /><br />

                Tom Martin<br /><br />

                AZ China</p>';



        // multiple recipients

        $to  = $emailaddress;

        //$to = 'c23gooey@gmail.com';



        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";



        // Additional headers

        $headers .= 'From: AZ China <tom.martin@az-china.com>' . "\r\n";



        // Mail it

        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

    }

}
```

Comment: The link in the body would go to a page on your site setup to read a unique ID you've provided in a GET url, which will be used to lookup the user and perform whatever action they've initiated (and then remove that unique ID so it will not be actionable, or set some type of status = `activated`, or whatever). The point is that url, maybe `http://yoursite.com/renew.php?acct=[uniqid()]`, will do the sending, but needs to be initiated by the user, and the ID in the url should be a uniquely identifying row in a table that de-references the user's account and allows you to work on it from there.

Comment: @JaredFarrish wouldn't that be an answer

Comment: @user2210482 you do understand that the mail you're sending is just text. End user reading your mail won't magically have php mail() capabilities no matter what you write, so you need to do it the way Jared Farrish explained.

Comment: @eis, I added something. It's pseudo-code, but gets the general idea across.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just want to confirm that jareds answer is the only way to do something like this? If so, do you mind explaining the steps a bit more slowly. i am relatively new to this, as you can tell.

Comment: @user2210482 it is pretty much the only way to implement what you've requested. However, if you want to strip down your requirements, you could just have a "mailto" link in your email that would open another email message as prefilled that a user must send. You could have a rule configured in that email box to reply with a "Thank you" email to these emails. That's considerably easier to implement, but does not have all the features you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

A way to handle this is to setup a lookup or junction table, where you will store a a uniquely identifying ID that you generate per renewal request with the corresponding user ID.

This table may look something like:

```
renewals
-------------------------------
renewid              | userid
-------------------------------
[output of uniqid()] | bob
[output of uniqid()] | bill
[output of uniqid()] | sarah
...
```

When you run your script to gather the soon-to-expire list of accounts, add a a bit to the email step that:

```
while ...

    $renewid = uniqid();

    $renewurl = "http://.../renew.php?req=$renewid";

    // Put that URL in the body of the email.

    $renewsql = "
INSERT INTO renewals (
    renewid, userid
) VALUES (
    '$renewid', '{$email['userid']}'
)
";

    if ($db->query($renewsql)) {
        mail(...);
    }
}
```

Assuming that `$email['userid']` is whatever that user ID field is called, and that you've selected it in the query for `$emails`.

Then, with a URL like `http://.../renew.php?req=$renewid`, you might do something like this in `renew.php`:

```
<?php

$renew = preg_replace('/^a-z0-9/i', '', $_GET['req']);

if ($renew != '') {
    $which = $db->query("
SELECT userid 
FROM renewals 
WHERE renewid = '$renew' 
LIMIT 1
");

    if ($which->hasRows()) {
        $userid = $which->get(0)->field('userid');

        // do whatever renewal stuff with the $userid

        $db->query("DELETE FROM renewals WHERE renewid = '$renewid'");
    } 
}
```

Another thing you could do is add an `expires` column, so that you can periodically clean out old renewal requests. But more or less, this is the general idea.

Comment: Thankyou so much Jared for the detailed answer. I will give it a go. All else fails, I will go for the simple mailto link. For the latter, is there anyway to have a template message already in the email box? Such as "I want to renew my subscription to _____,"